How may I disable the post-processing (additional filtering) of code completion suggestions?
I would like to add support for spelling correction to the code completion logic of my extension, and have found that I can return an instance of CompletionList with isIncomplete=true to have VSCode call my onCompletion handler on each keystroke, but it will apply an additional filter atop my suggestions no matter what I do. The filter matches exact keystrokes, which makes things like spelling correction impossible. Is there a way to disable this post-processing logic in VSCode?
